# Removing text from background with opacity

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, background

I have a png diagramm (see first image), which has some sort of opacity. I need to remove the text and insert the translated one preferably without hurting this opacity. 
I tried many things in Photoshop, and the least bad was to just rectangle select and delet the text. But I would like to know the proper solution for removing the text, because when applying non-white background to the edited picture it looks ugly - as show on the second picture.

Any comment and idea is welcome. Thanks

[image: png with opacity]

[image: ugly pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very translucent white over the entire image. You can use a **Layer Mask** to hide that white....

- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-click the image thumbnail in the **Layers Panel** to load the transparency as a selection.
- With the selection active, click the **New Layer Mask** icon at the bottom of the **Layers Panel**
- Highlight the **Layer Mask** you just created and adjust the contrast of the mask. I used **Image > Adjustments > Levels**, but `Curves` should all work.
- Finally, take a brush and paint black on areas the mask didn't pick up, like that white edge at the top of the image.

[image]

You should then be able to add any solid layer under the image and not have to deal with the translucent white.

[image]

The reality is, if you are replacing all the text labels, it may be nearly as fast to redraw such a simple graph.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! And the idea of redrawing this image is certainly a good one. The only thing is, that I have similar, but more complicated diagramms too - so it is nice to have a solution for this case also.

What is not so clear for me, that how could I reproduce that gradient on the lines with two big dots at the end. Could you give a hint on that too?

Comment: I am currently unable to upvote your answer - I need to get more "reputation" apparently :)

Comment: No problem. Seems Stack altered that for new users at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I realise you have already chosen best answer, but there is another way to do this and still maintain the semi transparent areas, using Photoshop.

1. Select a blank part of the semi transparent background with the rectangle select tool, and create a Pattern from by clicking Edit > Define Pattern.
2. Select around the text you want to delete, and hit delete.
3. Then Edit > Fill > and Choose the pattern you made.  The deleted area will be filled with the semi transparent colour.

Here's the result - I removed all the text - the semi-transparent areas are intact.

[image]

Now all you need to do is add the text.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! (I still can't upvote, but I would love to.)